# Is there a way to prevent a contentEditable element from scrolling when the cursor reaches the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, contenteditable

For example, I have a contentEditable div and I can type in it. When the text reaches the bottom of the div, the browser automatically scrolls the div so that the end of the text and the cursor are still visible.

How do I prevent the div from scrolling so that the inputted text goes past the bottom of the div and so that you can no longer see the cursor while you type?

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is like in Photoshop: when you make a text box, and type too much, the cursor continues past the bottom of the box and you can't see what you are typing. If you expand the box, you'll see all the hidden text.

**EDIT 2/7/2012 9:27am:** This is what I have right now, but it looks glitchy because the scroll position is adjusted AFTER the keyup event: http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/hgkak/6/ So before the keyup event, the cursor gets temporarily placed into view (for each keystroke). I'd like there to be no jumping, and for the cursor to remain below the end of the green div when there is excess text without the view jumping around (the jumping seems like an amateur hack on my part :D)

Comment: So you're looking for a complicated hack to make your website unintuitive and harder to use and you're willing to spend 200 reputation on it? How did you ever get the idea that Photoshop is a good example of a user interface when it becomes more cluttered and confusing with every version? I realise this comment sounds nasty but have you actually considered that there's a really good reason why contentEditable acts the way it does?

Comment: ive tested the fiddle and in firefox 13 work good without jumpings...

Comment: @SpliFF there are definitely justifiable UI cases for this kind of feedback, basically any interface where the inputted text will be shown in a fixed-size container on the front end.

Comment: @Daniel: Then why would you even allow the input text to go beyond the size of the textarea? You're still not solving a real problem but hacks like this are bound to create a few.

Comment: @SpliFF it's not always convenient to calculate character limits based on container height, especially if users are able to select font, etc.  Sometimes previewing final display for users in editor interface is preferable to dynamically measuring heights.  I agree that it's not ideal, but I don't think it's universally abhorrent.

Comment: I agree with Daniel... My text containers are resizeable, and allow for different font sizes, font weights, line-heights, etc. Calculating how many characters fits in the container with all these parameters constantly changing would be nasty too. That'd definitely work with a textarea, but this is not the case. I thought there might be some simpler solution, like what I'm trying to do with this question. The concept implies to the user in a perfectly simple way that the container is the limiting factor to how much text fits in it.

Comment: Say for example, the user has typed too much and the text is past the bottom. He can make the overall font size smaller and then everything might fit. That would be MUCH better than having text truncated or limited.

Comment: And what I want is not unintuitive in my humble opinion. In Julian D's answer you can see the exact effect I'm looking for. Yeah, its a hack, but to a non-technical user who cares? It works just like it should and the user gets the idea... e.g. "oh, the box is too small.. I'll resize the box, backspace the heck back into view, or make the font smaller."... This type of functionality works well because all my text boxes are strategically position by users on top of image/video layouts that appear on HD displays, not forms for collecting data.

Comment: @SpliFF The question wasn't: "Is this a good UI idea: xyz", the question was "I want to do xyz, how do I do it?" We are here to solve technical issues. It is also quite arrogant to think that you can think of 100% of situations where trusktr could have applied this and then decide that it is a bad idea in 100% of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's try a hack:

- first we try to prevent or revert any scrolling
- whenever the user presses a key we turn the element's `overflow` property to `visible` to avoid scrolling of the content, but hide the element at the same time by setting its `opacity` to 0. Immediately afterwards we switch `overflow` back to `hidden` and show the element again.
- to avoid flickering we create a clone of the editable element (with `overflow: hidden`) and show this element while the original one is hidden.

Here we go (uses jQuery for DOM convenience):

```
$(function() {

    var editableElement = $('#editable'), clonedElement;

    // Revert any scrolling                    
    editableElement.on("scroll", function(event) {
        editableElement.scrollTop(0);

        // Try to prevent scrolling completely (doesn't seem to work)
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    // Switch overflow visibility on and off again on each keystroke.
    // To avoid flickering, a cloned element is positioned below the input area
    // and switched on while we hide the overflowing element.
    editableElement.on("keydown", function() {

        // Create a cloned input element below the original one
        if (!clonedElement) {
            var zIndex = editableElement.css('zIndex');
            if (isNaN(parseInt(zIndex, 10))) {
                zIndex = 10;
                editableElement.css({zIndex: zIndex});
            }    

            clonedElement = editableElement.clone();
            clonedElement.css({
                zIndex: zIndex-1,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: editableElement.offset().top,
                left: editableElement.offset().left,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                // Set pseudo focus highlighting for webkit
                // (needs to be adapted for other browsers)
                outline: 'auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color'
            });
            editableElement.before(clonedElement);
        } else {
            // Update contents of the cloned element from the original one
            clonedElement.html(editableElement.html());
        }

        // Here comes the hack:
        //   - set overflow visible but hide element via opactity.
        //   - show cloned element in the meantime
        clonedElement.css({opacity: 1});
        editableElement.css({overflow: 'visible', opacity: 0});

        // Immediately turn of overflow and show element again.
        setTimeout(function() {
            editableElement.css({overflow: 'hidden', opacity: 1});
            clonedElement.css({opacity: 0});
        }, 10);

    });
});
```

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/green/GRvgd/) to play with the above code.

Note that this may not be a complete solution (I have only tried it with Safari, Chrome and Firefox yet), but for the tested browsers it seems to work. You may want to fine-tune and polish your implementation (e.g. focus highlighting). In the jsFiddle example I have also turned off spell checking to avoid flickering markings.

Comment: Wow, that's freackin' awesome! It looks very convincing.

Comment: Hey, do you have an idea of what Rustam means for me to do with his pseudo code in his answer? After reading and analyzing it, it seems that it will also be jumpy just like in my jumpy example...

Comment: Damn, I didn't realize stackoverflow's auto-award mechanism doesn't award the full bounty. :/

Comment: Don't worry, thanks for the generous bounty points, highly appreciated.
Regarding your comment question: No, sorry, I don't really understand @Rustam's answer. Does he want to emulate the editable behavior? In my experience rolling your own implementation for selections, cursor keys and things like pasting is a pretty difficult task...

Comment: Nothing is == NaN, you have to use the isNaN() function

Answer (score 3):

You need to have parent div (A) with `overflow:hidden;position:relative` and static height or min-height.

Inside this parent you have children div (B) with `contenteditable="true"` and `style="position:absolute;width:100%;left:0;top:0"`

Height of div A must be like `integer * line-height of div B`

---

After that you need to include [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) and jQuery library

Bind on div B keyup event function{

Use rangy for create in current cursor place empty `span`.

Get [offset().top](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) from this span and compare it with `offset().top +`[`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) from div A. If first is large then second -> you need to scroll down div B.

To scroll down just change current `css top` on `+= line-height of div B`

Destroy empty span.

(if cursor position fails -> you need to previously save it before creating span and restore cursor position after destroying span)

}

---

Also you need to emulate all with arrow keys. In that case you need to create switch selector with [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) on keyup in div B. Keycodes are [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Scroll if cursor position is out from visible range in div A (algorithm similar to what I wrote above)

---

*Yes, this is not an easy way, but it works*

Comment: I've never used that range stuff. Does it work smoothly? Right not I'm doing something simple where on keyup I do scrollTop(0) for div A. It looks glitchy though because the div A scrolls to the cursor at first, then on keyup scrolls back to the top, for every key press.

Comment: Rangy standardizes rangy and selection functionality in IE to native (like jQuery). If you know principles of selection and range (this is absolutely different things), it work smoothly.

Comment: If you want to cancel default action of pressing key -> you need to bind event on 'keydown' and after all code write 'return false'

Comment: This is what I had so far, but it looks glitchy: http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/hgkak/5/ As you can see, it keeps the cursor past the end of the green div, but before the keyup event fires the cursor is temporarily in view, making it look jumpy. Will you method fix that?

Comment: I'll have to see if I can use your method to make it happen when I get to it this weekend... Could you perhaps make an example in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I think this exsamples are better http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/index.html . You need only 4 first exsamples.

Comment: About jsfiddle.net/trusktr/hgkak/5 : you need CSS word-wrap: break-word (http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/). About jump - only if you will do event on keydown and disable default action - you will not see jumping

Comment: Hello Rustam, if I prevent default (`return false;`) on keyup then we can not type any characters... Also, looking at what you suggested, it seems that it will also be jumpy... If you could show a working example, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting style="overflow:hidden;" on the div

Comment: That doesn't work because the div still scrolls. The only thing that does is hide the scroll bar. Thanks for the idea though. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Add a Div that overlaps the bottom with a higher z-index? You can either make the editable area very tall as to not make a difference. Then you'd have to make the covering div dragable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Can you post a jsfiddle example?

Comment: He means make an edit area that's taller than you need then pull some opaque content up over the bottom of it so it's covered up. This will cut off the bottom border of the text area though so you may have to put a top border on your shroud to compensate. This technique will fail though because the resize handle will also be covered.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was proposing. I figured you could make the overlaid div resizable (height only). But that may be more trouble than it's worth. I'd have to try it when I have some free time.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Well it seems like that might not work in my case because there is stuff underneath the text box. The text box appears on top of other images, so hiding the bottom of the text box would also hide the stuff that is supposed to show from underneath the text box, if I'm imagining what your suggesting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#mydiv").height(document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollHeight);

    $("#mydiv").keyup(function(){

        $(this).height(0).height(document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollHeight);

    });

});
```