# Prevent auto-scroll of contenteditable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have element over image that is editable. And when writing text inside it as soon as cursor leaves wrapper it's scrolled and placed in view. How to fix it (if possible using only CSS, prefer not to change structure).

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap .item {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .5);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  <div class="item" contenteditable="true">Write HERE to get very long text and see scroll</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want editable div to remain in wrapper boundaries even if text is too long?

Comment: @Armin Yes, and if overflowed - don't scroll whole wrapper, just keep invincible.

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated code. Line will not break, and image will not be scrolled:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap .item {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .5);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  <div class="item" contenteditable="true">Write HERE to get very long text and see scroll</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It must not be auto-breakable text. Also I don't want to have it always visible, just do not scroll image on typing single line

Comment: @Justinas Sorry, I misunderstood. Can you check my updated version?

Answer (score 1):

A solution inspired by @Julian D. [awesome hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254438/1181905)
Still not perfect as there is some weird flickering that show at some point due to the switching of opacity.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap .item {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .5);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 60px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var editableElement = $('#editable'), clonedElement;

    // Revert any scrolling                    
    editableElement.on("scroll", function(event) {
      editableElement.scrollTop(0);

      // Try to prevent scrolling completely (doesn't seem to work)
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });

    // Switch overflow visibility on and off again on each keystroke.
    // To avoid flickering, a cloned element is positioned below the input
    // and switched on while we hide the overflowing element.
    editableElement.on("keydown", function() {

      // Create a cloned input element below the original one
      if (!clonedElement) {
        var zIndex = editableElement.css('zIndex');
        if (isNaN(parseInt(zIndex, 10))) {
            zIndex = 10;
            editableElement.css({zIndex: zIndex});
        }    

        clonedElement = editableElement.clone();
        clonedElement.css({
            zIndex: zIndex-1,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: editableElement.offset().top,
            left: editableElement.offset().left,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            // Set pseudo focus highlighting for webkit
            // (needs to be adapted for other browsers)
            outline: 'auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color'
        });
        editableElement.before(clonedElement);
      } else {
        // Update contents of the cloned element from the original one
        clonedElement.html(editableElement.html());
      }

      // Here comes the hack:
      //   - set overflow visible but hide element via opactity.
      //   - show cloned element in the meantime
      clonedElement.css({opacity: 1});
      editableElement.css({overflow: 'visible', opacity: 0});

      // Immediately turn of overflow and show element again.
      setTimeout(function() {
        editableElement.css({overflow: 'hidden', opacity: 1});
        clonedElement.css({opacity: 0});
      }, 0);

    });
  });
</script>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  <div id="editable" class="item" contenteditable="true">Write HERE to get very long text and see scroll</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position: fixed; instead of absolute  that will stop the scrolling as below

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap .item {
  position: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .5);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  <div class="item" contenteditable="true">Write HERE to get very long text and see scroll</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting `pos: fixed` will make element pop-out of wrapper and on scrolling will fail to remain in same place of parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just give pixel value for the width of contenteditable div.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap .item {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  width:100px;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .5);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  <div class="item" contenteditable="true">Write HERE to get very long text and see scroll</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't set it as fixed size, it must be dynamic.

Comment: @Justinas you can give value dynamically but value unit should be in `px`